# UNDEFINED Cursor in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create function in mySQL but getting an error saying UNDEFINED Cursor :REVERSE.

Below is my code :

```
        create function check_data (v_dcrpath VARCHAR(4000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
 BEGIN
  DECLARE v_dcrpath_value varchar(1000);
  DECLARE REVERSE CURSOR FOR select_statement
   OPEN REVERSE 1..length(v_dcrpath)
      loop
        if substr(v_dcrpath,i,1) = '/' then
           v_dcrpath_value := substr(v_dcrpath, i+1);
           exit;
        end if;
   end loop;

   IF v_dcrpath_value = 'data' then
      return 'true';
   else
      return 'false';
   end if;
fetch  into;
end;
close ;
```

Any Suggestion

Comment: Is this meant to be looking for the last folder called data in the path?

Comment: MySQL and PL/SQL are very different, so you'll need to rewrite some of your logic. For example, MySQL doesn't support the `..` range operator.

Comment: Yes I am trying to get the last folder path by using function, but not able to find the right code for that.

Comment: How about Like '%/data' or like '%/data/%' ?

Comment: It will not work for this sample data .   /templatedata/composite-item/page/data/3_Local/EU/fr_BE/aqws_dddddd_fr_BE_8004      |
| /templatedata/composite-item/page/data/3_Local/EU/fr_BE/Electronics/rvw_fr_BE_12238 |
| /templatedata/composite-item/page/data/3_Local/EU/fr_BE/Localtest_fr_BE_12153       |
| /templatedata/composite-item/page/data/3_Local/EU/fr_BE/newdcrvalid_fr_BE_12417     |
| /templatedata/composite-item/page/data/3_Local/EU/fr_BE/page_load_3_fr_BE_11        |
| /templatedata/composite-item/page/data/3_Local/EU/fr_BE/ss1_fr_BE_12051             |

Comment: Oh dear, that's not the best choice for database content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably missed to define the cursor `REVERSE`. Try to declare it like this

```
DECLARE REVERSE CURSOR FOR select_statement
```

Comment: Getting an error now ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select_statement
   OPEN REVERSE 1..length(v_dcrpath)
      loop
        if subs' at line 4

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code which you are using?

Comment: Ooh man!!! select_statement meant your select statement on which you want your cursor to execute!!!

Comment: OH. See i have very little knowledge about function in sql. I want to execute query like <<SELECT DCRPath  FROM DCR_Dependencies WHERE DCRPath LIKE '%/fr_BE/%' AND DCRPath LIKE '%/gallery/%' AND check_data(DCRPath)='true'>> for which i need to create such type of function. If possible can you make the required changes in that function.

Comment: Hi can you post the code or amend the existing one which will work on my scenario.